# Google analytics management API returning status "FAILED"

Tags: google-analytics-api

I have a python script which every day asks the [management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/unsampledReports) for an unsampled report and has been working great so far. Today the management API, after attempting some GET requests (I am sending a request every 60 seconds in order to check for the report to have the status "FINISH"), is returning a "FAILED" status. How can I check why is that [status](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/unsampledReports#status) being returned? What are the different possibilities? Now I am asking the API for yesterday report, which yesterday was returned as expected, in order to see if there is a problem with the API or, maybe, a change in the data pushed to the GA. So far its seems it will return the "FAILED" status.

Otherwise how can I contact the GA Management API support?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Edit: Previous report (from previous dates) are failing too.

Comment: This doesn't sound like it is necessarily an issue with the Management API. It could be that the process timed out. You can always re-attempt a failed request (perhaps requesting a smaller data set), but requests can fail both from the API and from the Web Interface. It sounds like you are using the API correctly.

Comment: I was able to contact analytics support and they ended up escalating it to the engineering team. After the weekend they were able to fix it.

Thanks for taking the time and sorry for not updating the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, the problem was solved by google analytics's engineering team on their side.